# how to control player location and trigger animation for rock climbing

Tags: animation, game-engine, logic-bricks

I need to make the cubes trigger a climbing animation and be used to control hand and feet locations. Ideally I would like a script to be able to control the armature based of a cube configuration.

if not this way then how would I get the climbing animations to be triggered and get the animation to line up with the holds?

I really need to know how to approach the problem, 
can this be done just with logic bricks or is scripting a must in this case?

really just need to be pointed in the right direction, thanks
[image]

Comment: probably use some bone constraints

Comment: how does that work?